# Using ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to change bitmap color causing weird result in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, png, colormatrix

I get a bitmap from resource using this method and draw it using Canvas.drawBitmap within a class extended from SurfaceView:

```
    private Bitmap getImage(Context context, int imageId) {
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    context.getResources().openRawResource(imageId, value);
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inTargetDensity = value.density;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), imageId,
            opts);
}
```

This bitmap displays itself without any problem. But when I want to change it's color using the following method and draw this new bitmap, the it will always lose some part of the whole image.

```
    public static Bitmap changeColor(Bitmap bmpOriginal, float degree) {
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(),
            bmpOriginal.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Set the two bitmaps with the same density.
    //But it seems no use now
    // try {
    // bmp.setDensity(bmpOriginal.getDensity());
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    // // TODO: handle exception
    // Log.v("ImageTools_changeColor", "" + e.toString());
    // }
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setRotate(0, degree);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmp;
}
```

I tried many search results from the web, but still don't know why. 
I think the problem may also come from another source: the resource bitmap itself. It is a 32bit png file 65*161 big and with a size of 1.59KB, not very big. So I get another png and draw with the same method, nothing goes wrong! So these two pngs' links are also given here for you to find the crux of the problem. Thanks a loooot!

================[The png causing problem](http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2012/329499/2012052719244378.png) VS [The png without problem](http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2012/329499/2012052719252769.png)=============

Comment: "it will always lose some part of the whole image" - What do you mean? What part of the image? Can you share a screen?

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov Here is a screen, http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2012/329499/2012052720090210.png, you can see the lower part of this image is lost. thx:)

Comment: I am looking at your problem but I can't find a solution. I can't even reproduce the problem on my machine. Are you sure the problem is in changeColor()? Comment out cm.setRotate(0, degree); and see what happens. Or maybe something is blocking you image. Try moving it to a different position.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov Oh God, how silly I was! Look at this: Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(),bmpOriginal.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888); I should use bmpOriginal.getHeight() as the second parameter. Sorry.